# Получить имя пользователя

Tags: vkontakte-api

Мне надо просто получить имя пользователя, имея его id. Пытаюсь сделать по документации с помощью метода [users.get](https://vk.com/dev/users.get). Формирую ссылку и пытаюсь перейти по ней:

`https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?params[client_id]=xxx&params[client_secret]=xxx&params[access_token]=xxx&redirect_uri=https://mysite.ru&params[user_ids]=1&params[fields]=last_name%2Cfirst_name&params[name_case]=Nom&params[v]=5.78`

Но мне упорно пишет "User authorization failed: no access_token passed." Что я делаю не так? Уже все коды приложения какие у меня есть я туда впихнул. Не знаю что еще надо...

P.S. В access_token пихаю сервисный ключ приложения.

Comment: Ответ вам уже написали, но мне стало интересно — откуда вы этот `params[]` вообще взяли и почему?

Comment: @andreymal доки сбивают с толку. Я нажал кнопку в форме (у них там форма с запросом) и сформировалась такая ссылка. Только сейчас понял что она работает лишь на сайте.

Comment: Не припомню там такого, не покажете где это сформировалась такая ссылка?

Comment: @andreymal [http://skrinshoter.ru/i/280518/ddFMxWRw.png](http://skrinshoter.ru/i/280518/ddFMxWRw.png)

Comment: Не, ну это ж ссылка вовсе не из API, не нужно было туда смотреть)

Comment: @andreymal ну а нормальная ссылка там к сожалению нигде не формируется

Comment: Но как её формировать - рассказано по ссылке из ответа)

Comment: Впрочем, соглашусь с тем, что формировать ссылку по параметрам из формы лишним не будет. Повод написать фичреквест в поддержку)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изучите https://vk.com/dev/api_requests
В параметрах нужно передавать только названия полей, без params[].
То есть

```
https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=210700286&fields=bdate&access_token=533bacf01e11f55b536a565b57531ac114461ae8736d6506a3&v=5.78
```

Comment: А черт, точно. Гребаная документация. Путает.